# Split a character column from a dataframe based on specific token

Tags: r, split, dplyr

I have a dataframe `df` and the first column looks like this:

```
[1] "760–563" "01455–1" "4672–04" "11–31234" "22–12" "11111–53" "111–21" "17–356239" "14–22352" "531–353"
```

I want to split that column on `-`.

What I'm doing is

```
strsplit(df[,1], "-")
```

The problem is that it's not working. It returns me a list without splitting the elements. I already tried adding the parameter `fixed = TRUE` and putting a regular expressing on the `split` parameter but nothing worked.

What is weird is that if I replicate the column on my own, for example:

```
myVector <- c("760–563" "01455–1" "4672–04" "11–31234" "22–12" "11111–53" "111–21" "17–356239" "14–22352" "531–353")
```

and then apply the `strsplit`, it works.

I already checked my column type and class with

`class(df[,1])` and `typeof(df[,1])` and both returns me `character`, so it's good.

I was also using the dataframe with dplyr so it was of the type `tbl_df`. I converted it back to `dataframe` but didn't work too.

Also tried `apply(df, 2, function(x) strsplit(x, "-", fixed = T))` but didn't work too.

Any clues?

Comment: Assuming `df[,1]` is your column to split. Try using `str_split_fixed(df[,1], "-", 2)` . It splits the column in to two parts. In case if you need to assign new columns please use `df$first_part <- str_split_fixed(df[,1], "-", 2)[,1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you did it, but you have two different types of dashes:

```
charToRaw(substr("760–563", 4, 4))
#[1] 96
charToRaw("-")
#[1] 2d
```

So the `strsplit()` is working just fine, it's just that the dash isn't there in your original data. Adjust this, and away you go:

```
strsplit("760–563", "–")
#[[1]]
#[1] "760" "563"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just split on a non-numeric character

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  separate(your_column, 
           c("first_number", "second_number"),
           sep = "[^0-9]")
```

Comment: Or just `separate(your_column, c("first_number", "second_number"))` since `separate()` guesses the delimiter.